# Why am I getting segmentation fault for the following code?

Tags: c, string

The question is to alphabetically sort the given string inputs in ascending order. I wrote the following code for the same. But after printing the entered names the program instead of sorting the strings is giving segmentation fault. I have spent good time over the issue but couldn't figure out anything. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int x,i,j,length;
    printf("Enter the number of names you want to sort.\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    char *names[x],*p,name[50],*t;
    printf("Enter the names:\n");
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        scanf(" %[^\n]",name);
        length = strlen(name);
        p = (char *)malloc(length+1);
        strcpy(p,name);
        names[i] = p;
    }
    printf("Entered names are:\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",names[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\nThe sorted names are:\n");
    for(i=0;i<x-1;i++)
    {

        for(j=i+1;j<x;j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(names[i],names[j])>0)
            {
                strcpy(t,names[i]);
                strcpy(names[i],names[j]);
                strcpy(names[j],t);
            }
        }    
    }
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",names[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcpy(t, names[i]);` Hmmm.. what does `t` point to ?

Comment: @WhozCraig a character

Comment: @user3121023 nice point! but how do i fix that?

Comment: @user3121023 but i have seen programs working fine this way also

Comment: @Sukrit it's not because it *seems to* work fine that it is bug-free...

Comment: How about no `strcpy` *at all* when sorting. You have an array of pointers. So... swap *pointers* (which is probably the point of this little exercise in the first place). That will eliminate the erroneous copy into the unallocated `t`, *and* fix the problem @user3121023 stated below my prior comment. In short, it fixes your code.

Comment: @WhozCraig let me try

Comment: @WhozCraig Woa it worked! I am a bit confused now. Sometimes I try swapping pointers like I tried doing it in place of strcpy(p,name) as above to p = name but it created problems (it only took the last input x times). And now strcpy didn't work but the simple pointer swapping did. I can't figure it out. Help Me!

Comment: @Sukrit, you can consider pointers as `uint32_t`: they are ”just" values you can assign, just as regular `int`s. It's just their value that is interpreted as an *address*, rather than a random integer (i.e. its value has a special meaning).

Comment: @Matthieu Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't allocate `t` so the `strcpy(t,names[i])` will segfault.

You can also use `strdup()`<sup>1</sup> to duplicate your strings (instead of `malloc()` and `strcpy()`).

And, as your array is of `char*` elements, you can just swap them directly:

```
t=names[i];
names[i]=names[j];
names[j]=t;
```

Regarding your question about pointers, you can consider pointers as `uint32_t`: they are ”just" values you can assign, like regular integers. It's just their value that is interpreted as an address, rather than a random integer (i.e. its value has a special meaning for the computer, as it is strongly linked to memory).

<sup>1</sup>: As noted by @WhozCraig, `strdup()` is *not* part of the standard library so you'll have to `#include` the appropriate headers for your platform (it is really widely spread though and hardly a problem).

Comment: Note that `strdup` is handy as all get-out, but it's also not in the language standard library. It is *probably* provided by your vendor anyway, but the feature-enabement setup for POSIX should be done. [See here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup).

Comment: @WhozCraig, true. Let me add that. (And coding an equivalent yourself is not a big task anyway. Doing so efficiently, on the other hand...)

Comment: `strdup` is not in the C standard, but it is included in a large variety of systems (Windows, Linux, BSD, OSX). Any POSIX-wannabe definitely has it (and `strndup`, too).